# Determine complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, while-loop, complexity-theory

Assume  algo(p) is an algorithm that take Theta(p) time to execute and does not change p. Determine the running time complexity of the following algorithm:

```
Algo2(n) 
begin
p=1;
while p <= n 
    begin 
    algo(p)
    p=2*p
    end;
end;
```

Really have no idea where to begin, I was thinking O(logn) maybe since p=p*2 but then there is an algo(p) in the while loop and I don't know how that would effect things.

Comment: How did you get log(n) from p = p*2

Comment: @TwilightSparkleTheGeek Read the answer given by Henrik, he explains why the answer to this problem is Theta(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Big Theta(n):

It calls `algo(p)` O(logn) times with p = 1, 2, 4, ..., 2^(floor(logn)).
This is Theta(1 + 2 + ... + 2^(floor(logn)) = Theta(2^(floor(logn+1)-1) = Theta(n).

Comment: what does floor mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To get an easier problem, you can set it like this :

```
Algo(n)
  begin
  p=1, i=1
  while p<= n
    begin
    algo(p)
    p=2*p
    i++
    end
  end
```

which you can rewrite like that :

```
Algo(n)
  begin
  i=1
  while 2^(i-1)<=n
    begin
    algo(2^(i-1))
    i++
    end
  end
```

Then, as Henrik said :

> It calls algo(p) O(logn) times with p = 1, 2, 4, ..., 2^(floor(logn)).
>   This is Theta(1 + 2 + ... + 2^(floor(logn)) =
>   Theta(2^(floor(logn+1)-1) = Theta(n).

Comment: That's not correct. The loop is executed O(logn) times, but the complexity of the whole algortithm including the calls to `algo` is Theta(n).

Comment: I misread his post. I'll correct my answer, thanks for pointing it out.